# Validate mobile phone numbers from all Europe

Tags: python, phone-number

I need to "filter" phone numbers depending in if they are mobile numbers or landline numbers and, if they are mobile numbers, send SMS.

I have numbers from all Europe.

Let's say this is a phone number list:

- 6xxxxxxxx (valid mobile number from Spain with no country prefix, I don't care as I can add the prefix myself)
- 9xxxxxxxx (landline number from Spain with no country prefix, I don't care as I can "delete" it from the list myself)
- 346yyyyyyyy (valid mobile number from Spain with country prefix)
- 324xxxxxxxx (valid mobile number from Belgium with country prefix)
- 336xxxxxxxx (valid mobile number from France with country prefix)

Is there any library that handles this (filtering valid mobile phone numbers from all Europe) without having to tell myself which country is the phone number from (prefix) and if it's mobile or landline?

I saw that there's [this library called phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/) and [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) but it is not clear to me if it is possible to use the combination of both to know if it is a mobile or not.

Comment: As you'll need a GDPR opt-in before sending the SMS, can't you simply add that question to that same opt-in form?

Comment: The problem is that I get the number list from a table in SQL Server and that is already filled with thousands of numbers and it is poorly managed so it's a mess. My internship adviser asked me to just send SMS using that table to valid mobile numbers corresponding to clients from Europe.